# Djongo Error: Keyword: FAILED SQL: SELECT %(0)s AS "a" FROM "testapp_test_db" WHERE "testapp_test_db"."id" = %(1)s LIMIT 1 Params: (1, 1)

Tags: django, mongodb, django-models, djongo

I have created two models in Django. The one is **Test_DB** and the other is **ForeignKey_Test**. The later models has a foreign key field which is referring to the **Test_DB**. When I tried to enter data from the the Django's default admin panel, I got the following error.

[image]

```
The above exception ( Keyword: FAILED SQL: SELECT %(0)s AS "a" FROM "testapp_test_db" WHERE "testapp_test_db"."id" = %(1)s LIMIT 1 Params: (1, 1) Version: 1.3.6 Sub SQL: None FAILED SQL: None Params: None Version: None) was the direct cause of the following exception:
```

What I am concluding that while parsing the SQL, Djongo expects two parameters to be passed. But currently it is being only one passed and that is the **id**. Can somebody tell me what's wrong here?

I can share any of the snippet of my project here.

**Models**

```
class Test_DB(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class ForeignKey_Test(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    test_id = models.ForeignKey(to='Test_DB', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

My database is in MongoDb and I am using Djongo.

**pip freeze**

```
asgiref==3.5.2
backports.zoneinfo==0.2.1
certifi==2022.9.24
charset-normalizer==2.1.1
coreapi==2.3.3
coreschema==0.0.4
Django==4.1.1
django-cors-headers==3.13.0
djangorestframework==3.14.0
djangorestframework-simplejwt==5.2.0
djongo==1.3.6
drf-yasg==1.21.3
idna==3.4
inflection==0.5.1
itypes==1.2.0
Jinja2==3.1.2
MarkupSafe==2.1.1
packaging==21.3
PyJWT==2.5.0
pymongo==3.12.3
pyparsing==3.0.9
pytz==2022.2.1
PyYAML==6.0
requests==2.28.1
ruamel.yaml==0.17.21
ruamel.yaml.clib==0.2.6
sqlparse==0.2.4
uritemplate==4.1.1
urllib3==1.26.12
```

Comment: I didn't get you but you can do that without custom SQL, mean use python

Comment: I am not using custom SQL. I am using Django's admin panel to insert data. But while inserting it's giving me this error. I only assumed that the SQL that Django's admin panel is parsing is creating an error because it is not getting the field name in the params list.

Answer (score -1):

its not `test_id = models.ForeignKey(to='Test_DB', on_delete=models.CASCADE)`
its `test_id = models.ForeignKey(Test_DB, on_delete=models.CASCADE)`

hope you get it :)

Comment: Still getting the same error